# Performance tuning for prepared statement

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g, prepared-statement, query-performance

I am writing a program for fetching some 7 millions records from oracle database table and then reinserting them in another table. My program is as follows

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Test_5000 {

    public  void Test_5000() throws SQLException, IOException {
         long startTime = System.nanoTime();     //processing timer starts

         DriverManager.registerDriver( new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver() );

         Connection DBConn = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:oracle:thin:@IE1FUX004:1521:Database", "username", "password" );

        if (DBConn != null)
        {
            System.out.println("nSuccessfullly connected to Oracle DB");
            String SqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM Old_Table";

               Statement stmt = DBConn.createStatement();
               ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(SqlQuery);

               String InsertQuery = "INSERT INTO NEW_Table (AIRPORT_Id, "+ 
                       "AIRPORT_Name, "+ 
                       "PROCESSING_Time, "+ 
                       //some more 32 fields      
                        ") Values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
               PreparedStatement ps = DBConn.prepareStatement(InsertQuery);
               ps.setFetchSize(1000);
               int batchsize =1000;
               int count=0;
              int k =0;
               System.out.println(InsertQuery);

               while(rs.next())
               {
                   ps.setString(1,rs.getString(1));
                   ps.setString(2,rs.getString(2));
                   ps.setInt(3, 201804);
                   ps.setString(4,rs.getString(4));
                   ps.setString(5,rs.getString(5));
                   ps.setString(6,rs.getString(6));
                   ps.setString(7,rs.getString(7));
                   ps.setString(8,rs.getString(8));
                   ps.setInt(9,rs.getInt(9));
                   ps.setString(10,rs.getString(10));
                   ps.setString(11,rs.getString(11));
                   ps.setInt(12,rs.getInt(12));
                   ps.setString(13,rs.getString(13));
                   ps.setString(14,rs.getString(14));
                   ps.setInt(15,rs.getInt(15));
                   ps.setInt(16,rs.getInt(16));
                   ps.setInt(17,rs.getInt(17));
                   ps.setString(18,rs.getString(18));
                   ps.setString(19,rs.getString(19));
                   ps.setString(20,rs.getString(20));
                   ps.setString(21,rs.getString(21));
                   ps.setString(22,rs.getString(22));
                   ps.setString(23,rs.getString(23));
                   ps.setInt(24,rs.getInt(24));
                   ps.setString(25,rs.getString(25));
                   ps.setString(26,rs.getString(26));
                   ps.setInt(27,rs.getInt(27));
                   ps.setInt(28,rs.getInt(28));
                   ps.setString(29,rs.getString(29));
                   ps.setString(30,rs.getString(30));
                   ps.setInt(31,rs.getInt(31));
                   ps.setString(32,rs.getString(32));

                   ps.addBatch();
                   DBConn.setAutoCommit(false);
                   //autocommit off
                  k=k+1;

                   if(++count % batchsize==0)
                   {
                       ps.executeBatch();
                       System.out.println(k);
                   }



        } 
               ps.executeBatch();
               System.gc();

               System.out.println("" +count);

               DBConn.setAutoCommit(false);

               long endTime = System.nanoTime();       //Processing time ends here
               long duration = (endTime - startTime);    
               System.out.println("time taken for processing is" + " " +duration);

               ps.close();
               rs.close();
               DBConn.close();

        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("nFailed to connect to Oracle DB");
        }
    }
    public static void main( String[] args) throws SQLException, IOException
      {
          System.out.println( "Started" );
          Test_5000 NFDAPT4 = new Test_5000();
          NFDAPT4.Test_5000();
          System.out.println( "End" );
      } 
    }
```

This program on an average is taking 5 mins to run and insert records into   database. JVM heap is definately not the issue. I found out optimal fetch size  is 1000 after experimenting on different Fetch sizes. Can anyone suggest any performance tuning in this program which will reduce its processing time. My requirement is perform this operation using java.
Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thank You in advance.

Comment: Here's a suggestion: Don't do it.  Use database tools to do it, not Java.  The only good reason I can think of to do such a thing is to move transactional records to reporting/historical schema.  Your operation suggests a schema that's not normalized.

Comment: why don't you execute `INSERT INTO NEW_Table SELECT * FROM OLD_TABLE`. ?

Comment: I have to perform some operations in  it. My requirment is ton perform this operation in java

Comment: What kind of processing do you need to do?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest insert directly instead of fetching and the inserting. Try query as

```
Insert into NEW_Table 
    Select * from OLD_Table
```

It will save your time for retrieval